# iPhones, iPods, iPads accelerometer sensitivity?

Tags: iphone, ipad, accelerometer, ipod

I've developed a movement detection application and I realize iPod3 and iPod4's accelerometer sensitivity and stability is very different. Whats about the other devices. Which ones are more sensitive, stable, and how much?

Thanks very very much all reply.

Answer (score 0):

Since the introduction of the iPhone 4 en iPod Touch 4gen (don't pin me down on the iPod touch) a Gyroscope is also available in the device. The Gyroscope will give a beter indication on movement then the accelerometer.

Comment: I know, but i can detect very small movements, example: vibrations and the gyroscope is only available in iPhone4 and iPod t 4g like you said.

Comment: You can detect very small movement because of the gyroscope, so device that don't have them, like the iphone (original, 3G and 3GS) won't detect the small movements because they have the accelerometer.

Comment: At now i can detect very very small movements with accelerometer in iPod touch 3 and 4rd, but i must override the calibration values for the good results. I want to know the ratio between device sensitivity. i use adaptive high-pass filter for filtering the noises.